# Angularjs list not refreshing on form submit using MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Some what new to the MEAN stack. Currently I'm reworking an small app I did through codeschool to be full MEAN stack. 
The app created can be seen here 
[Code School app](http://gentle-beyond-2407.herokuapp.com/)

In rewriting the app using the MEAN stack after submitting the form I must refresh the page to see the city added to the list. What do I need to fix so I don't need to refresh the page for the new Item to be added to the list?
If I'm missing any relevant code below here is my git hub link 
   [git hub link](https://github.com/jminterwebs/STBExpress/tree/MEAN)

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('Cityapp').controller('CityIndexController', function(City, $scope){
$scope.cities = City.query();
window.sc = $scope;

});

angular.module('Cityapp').controller('CityCreateController', function(City, $scope, $http){
 $scope.city = new City();
$scope.saveCity = function(city){
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/city',
    data: city})
.success( function(data, status, headers, config){

 console.log($scope.city);  
 console.log(data);
 console.log($scope.city);  
}).
error(function(data,status,headers,config){

jQuery('.alert').show();
console.log('nope');
});
};

});


   <form ng-controller="CityCreateController">
<legend> New City</legend>     
    <input for="City-group" name="City" id="City" type="text" ng-model="city.city" placeholder="City Name">
    <input for="City-group" name="desc" id="desc" type="text" ng-model="city.desc" placeholder="Description">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveCity(city)"/>
</form>



<ul ng-controller="CityIndexController"  class="city-list">
    <li ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <a href="#">
        {{city.city}}</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Does `data` look correct in the `success` callback?

Comment: "Object {city: "Test City", desc: "Test", id: 3} " that is what the console.log returns with a success. The Id is added via back end.

Comment: Please show us your template.

Comment: added html in post. No templates yet just the index html file.

Answer (score 0):

It should looks something like that

```js
;(function() {
  function Cities($http) {
    function City() {
      
    }
    
    City.prototype.save = function() {
      return $http.post('/api/city', this);
    };
    
    City.cities = [];
    
    City.add = function(city) {
      city.save().then(function() {
        City.cities.push(city);
      });
    };
    
    City.getAll = function() {
      $http.get('/api/cities').then(function(response) {
        City.cities = response.data.map(function(data) {
          return new City(data);
        });
        
        return cities;
      });
    };
    
    return City;
  }
  
  function CityCreateController(Cities) {
    var mv = this;
    
    mv.city = new Cities();
    
    mv.saveCity = function() {
      Cities.add(mv.city);
    };
  }
  
  function CityIndexController($scope, Cities) {
    var mv = this;
    
    $scope.$watchCollection(function() {
      return Cities.cities;
    }, function(cities) {
      mv.cities = cities || [];
    });
    
    Cities.getAll();
  }
  
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .factory('Cities', ['$http', Cities])
    .controller('CityCreateController', ['Cities', CityCreateController])
    .controller('CityIndexController', ['$scope', 'Cities', CityIndexController]);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <form ng-controller="CityCreateController as mv">
    <legend> New City</legend>     
    <input for="City-group" name="City" id="City" type="text" ng-model="mv.city.city" placeholder="City Name">
    <input for="City-group" name="desc" id="desc" type="text" ng-model="mv.city.desc" placeholder="Description">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mv.saveCity()"/>
  </form>
  
  <ul ng-controller="CityIndexController as mv"  class="city-list">
    <li ng-repeat="city in mv.cities">
    <a href="#">
        {{city.city}}</a></li> 
  </ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple fix

```
angular.module('Cityapp').controller('CityCreateController', function(City, $scope, $http){
$scope.cities = City.query();

$scope.city = new City();


$scope.saveCity = function(city){
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/city',
    data: city})
.success( function(data, status, headers, config){

$scope.cities.push({city: $scope.city.city,
                    desc: $scope.city.desc});



}).
error(function(data,status,headers,config){

jQuery('.alert').show();
console.log('nope');
});
};

});
```

Just added the

```
$scope.cities.push({city: $scope.city.city,
                    desc: $scope.city.desc});
```

to the .success. Works like it should. Now on to my next issue.